# phpMyAdmin doesn't load database import file with unsupported compression (application/gzip)

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, phpmyadmin, gzip

I upgraded from an older lubutu release to 14, now running PHP 5.5 and phpMyAdmin 4.0.10deb1, I regularly move small MySQL database exports between hosts (700KB gzip, around 7-10MB decompressed SQL).

> You attempted to load file with unsupported compression (application/gzip). Either support for it is not implemented or disabled by your configuration.

This was all working swimmingly on the older PHP setup, I'm not sure if it's a mime type thing or a configuration issue.

I can provide detailed phpinfo() dumps, but zlip is there, phar, etc:

```
Registered PHP Streams  https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip

Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls

Registered Stream Filters   zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk
```

The gzipped sql files aren't corrupt, they decompress and load manually without issue. If there's some configuration setting you can suggest I'll try that out

Comment: same problem here on ubuntu14.04 (was not a problem on 12.10). did you find a solution?

Comment: not yet, frustrating as.. next step is to dig through PHPMyAdmin and find out what it's expecting (stream/handler) etc

Comment: i found http://kb.parallels.com/en/116645 which says (effectively) its broken. thats in 2011!

Comment: see also http://serverfault.com/questions/197418/phpmyadmin-on-my-server-doesnt-support-compression

Comment: hmmm.. rereading that Registered Stream filters line and looking in my PHPMyAdmin import display it does indeed reflect no GZip support

**File may be compressed (bzip2, zip) or uncompressed.**

Comment: i've been wrestling with http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/09/install-latest-phpmyadmin-ubuntu-1204/ trying to get the latest ppa working. Can't log in (sigh)

Comment: got the ppa version working. had a problem with logging in: I'd login with valid credentials then it would redirect me back to the login page. Solution is to php5enmod mcrypt (and check phpinfo() that it is actually there). But that didn't solve the problem with gzip. I can't see any bug reports for this, can you? Surely someone has seen this before?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

i had the same problem under different configuration: Ubuntu 16.04 + PHP 7.0 + VirtualMin.
The zip library for php7.0 was simply not installed, so this fixed the problem:

```
apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

Edit: this works for php 7.0, the command must suit your php version (7.x)

Comment: This is the solution and it should be accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: It works also for me. P.S. Do not forget to restart apache service after the php7.0-zip installation.

Comment: Works well with amazon aws - yum install  php70-zip

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution these days. If still using PHP 5.6 you can  `apt install php5.6-zip` too

Comment: In Ubuntu distros, for php7.2 you can use `apt install php7.2-zip`

Answer (score 7):

Put the fix from here http://piwigo.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=151458

```
if (extension_loaded('zlib') && !function_exists('gzopen') && function_exists('gzopen64'))
{
  function gzopen($filename, $mode, $use_include_path = 0) {
    return gzopen64($filename, $mode, $use_include_path);
  }
}
```

in your /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php. Then it will survive an apt-get upgrade.

Comment: This works great when corrected by removing the `string` and `int` type hints from the `gzopen` function definition line because type hinting of scalar values like int or string is [not allowed](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

Comment: That actually worked! Feel it is annoying that ubuntu 14.04 has so many "why on earth is that changed"-surprises. Adding code for just importing a database dump is .. "good grief" :)

Comment: Anyone know a link to an official bug report or ticket for this ?

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative scenario for you.

Downloaded an SQL file from phpmyadmin to local laptop.
Before uploading to new server , I compressed locally form within finder. ( this is the mistake ) as this adds __MACOS folder to the compressed file. myfile.sql.zip

Generates the same error message.

> phpMyAdmin doesn't load database import file with unsupported
>   compression (application/gzip)

To stop that from happening, just gzip the file from the command line so you have..

gzip myfile.sql

> myfile.sql.gz

and upload that.

Answer (score 2):

For windows look for your php.ini and make sure zip extension is loaded and its line is not commented

```
extension=zip
```

if it is commented like this `;extension=zip` then remove the `;`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the comments, looking around some of the links I the issue **is** the Debian/Ubuntu choice of zlib providing the php function `gzopen64` rather than the expected `gzopen`, solution outlined here: http://kb.parallels.com/en/116645

/usr/share/phpmyadmin/import.php provides the following, changing gzopen to gzopen64 fixes the issue

```
        case 'application/gzip':
        if ($cfg['GZipDump'] && @function_exists('gzopen')) {
            $import_handle = @gzopen($import_file, 'r');
        } else {
            $message = PMA_Message::error(
                __('You attempted to load file with unsupported compression (%s). Either support for it is not implemented or disabled by your configuration.')
            );
            $message->addParam($compression);
            PMA_stopImport($message);
        }
        break;
```

Comment: agreed. dumb choice on Ubuntu's part. I'd prefer adding it in a config file not overwritten by apt, so the package can still be automatically updated. See my answer below. thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 8

```
yum install php-pecl-zip
```

Should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to see this error after installing `php*.zip`, then your phpMyAdmin configuration has zip compression explicitly disabled. Edit the config file, which is typically in `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` and set:

```
$cfg['ZipDump'] = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

you probably have to configure you apache server:

see this link for more informations : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html

Comment: It's not at the Apache level, this is unzipped at the PHP level alas

Answer (score -1):

Install the 7zip software and zip the data file in gz format and import it.
Your problem will be solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: refer to the accepted answer, it's a server package/config fix not client side zip/unzip